# Migrating to MongoDB: how to query GROUP BY + WHERE

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MYSQL table with records of people's names and the time of arrival expresed as a number. Think of it as a marathon. I want to know how many people arrived into a certain gap of time who where named the same, so:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM mydb.mytable
WHERE Time>=100 AND Time<=1000
GROUP BY name
```

And as results I get:

```
Susan, 1
John, 4
Frederick, 1
Paul, 2
```

I'm migrating to MongoDB now, and using Python to code (so I'm asking for Pymongo help). I tried looking for information about the GROUP BY equivalent (even when I have read that NoSQL databases are worse at this kind of operation than the SQL ones), but since they released the new agreggate API, I hjaven't been able to find a simple example like this solved with the group method, the Map-Reduce method or the brand new agreggate API.

Any help?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are examples of this all over the documentation, Google and this site.

Some references:

- http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/sum/

And for some code:

```
self.db.aggregate(
    # Lets find our records
    {"$match":{"Time":{"$gte":100,"$lte":1000}}}, 

    # Now lets group on the name counting how many grouped documents we have
    {"$group":{"_id":"$name", "sum":{"$sum":1}}} 
)
```

Comment: I think that using $name is what made me doubt how to do it, since name is the name of the field at the database, not a pymongo tag. Why is the name of the field to group by expressed like that?

Comment: @RomanRdgz If I am honest I do not know, it was a design decision that you would have to ask 10gen about, however, without the `$` the string is treated as literal within MongoDB, it is the `$` that makes MongoDB react as though it is a field value